# Monotonic function

Tags: derivatives, monotone-functions

Is the function $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, where $$f(x) = x^2+2x+2$$ a strictly increasing function or (non-strictly) increasing function?

I calculated $f'(x) = 2x+2$, so 
$$f'(x) = 0 \Rightarrow 2x+2 = 0 \Rightarrow x = -1 \\ \Rightarrow f'(x) \geq 0 \quad$$   when $x \in [-1,1]$.

It means that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing in $[-1,1]$? Or (non-strictly) increasing in $[-1,1]$?

Answer (score 2):

$y=(x+1)^2 +1;$

Let $a<b$, $a,b \in [-1,1]$, i.e $a +b >-2$.

$y(b)-y(a)=$

$ (b+1)^2-(a+1)^2=$

$ (b-a)(a+b+2) >0,$

and we are done.

Comment: quasi.Thanks.Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

$f'(x) >0$ for $x >-1$ so $f$ is strictly increasing in $(-1,1]$. But continuity of $f$ implies that it is actually strictly increasing in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Thank you!
But for example, $f(x) = x^3$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$? Or (nonstrictly) increasing?

Comment: $x^{3}$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I asked this because $f'(x) \geq 0$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, and not $f'(x) > 0$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$.



So, if $f'(x) \geq 0,\quad \forall x\in D$ it means that f(x) is strictly increasing on D?

Comment: Same argument as in my answer. If a continuous function is strictly increasing for $x <0$ and also for $x >0$ then  it is strictly increasing on the whole line.

Answer (score 1):

To show that $f$ is strictly increasing on $[-1,1]$, we need to show that for $a,b\in [-1,1]$
$$a < b \implies f(a) < f(b)$$
Thus, let $a,b\in [-1,1]$, with $a < b$.

Applying the Mean Value Theorem, it follows that
$$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
for some $c\in(a,b)$.

From $c > a$ and $a\ge -1$, we get $c > -1$, hence
\begin{align*}
&f'(c) > 0\qquad\text{[since $f'(x) > 0$ for $x > -1$]}\\[6pt]
\implies\;&\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} > 0\\[6pt]
\implies\;&f(b)-f(a) > 0\\[6pt]
\implies\;&f(a) < f(b)\\[6pt]
\end{align*}
therefore $f$ is strictly increasing on $[-1,1]$.